# How to make button retrieve information from a spinner and display it in a text view

Tags: android, android-widget

So I'm creating this small text based game for a class of mine and I have no idea how to do this:

I have a spinner that has a list of monsters. "id@spinnerMonster"
Also a button that says "Battle!" "id@btnBattle"

What I'm trying to make happen:

When you select a monster, let's say Training Dummy, and click the button, the button will trigger a textView that says "You have killed (Spinner Monster Name)!"

How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
btnBattle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

       public void onClick(View v) 
       {
               String selectedItem =  spinnerMonster.getSelectedItem().toString();      
               textview_id.setText("You have killed "+ selectedItem);
       }
});
```

Comment: I thought that would work but I keep getting a "could not resolve" error for 'textview_id' which I changed to textViewBattleResults and the 'spinnerMonsters' ??

Comment: Just kidding. I had to declare those 2... It works now. I could use some private lessons :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you need to use the OnItemSelected Listener then the arg2 gives u the position .Have a look at the code below for better understanding,hope this helps:

```
spn.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {


        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) {


        }
```

Use arg2 argument to get the item selected. it returns a integer value that is the position of the item in the list in spinner, now u know what is clicked so just set the textView to the appropriate msg.  If you need more detailed info let me know

Comment: Yeah I need more help. I've been programming for windows for years and I understand what your saying but I don't know how to apply it to the Android language.

Comment: Check Huseyin's answer below that should do it as well !  +1 for u huseyin :)